# Cannot import .RL: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Symbol'" error when Symbol is an .rl file

Tags: java, android

`import com.example.TestParser;`

The TestParser.rl file is where it should be but still I get an compile error. Is there anyway how to import .rl files?